# Remove/Add constraints - optaplanner

Tags: constraints, addition, drools, rules, optaplanner

Is it possible to make some rules be completely ignored? I have a set of rules, but I want the user to be able to add certain inputs, like they want rule 1, rule 2, rule 3, rule 5, but maybe not rule 4. So I want the program to recognise this, and not at all enter rule 4 while checking for constraint violation

How could I go about this?

Comment: See also the Parametrization pattern used in the examination example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a similar problem, except that I wanted users to control each rule weight [0 to 10] instead of a binary control [active - inactive]. I'm not sure about this being a performance optimized answer (worked for me in reasonable time, but of course that depends on your *corpus* size).

The approach we used was creating a *Singleton* which holds each rule weight set by the user in volatile memory, using a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` for faster random access (key = rule number, value = rule weight), as the inference engine may call it several times.

Then, in our rule files we checked if a given rule was active in `when` clause, and updated score in `then` clause according to the actual rule weight:

```
import my.rules.singleton.package.MyRulesWeightSingleton;

rule "1"
    when
        eval(MyRulesWeightSingleton.isRuleActive(1))
        //other conditions here.
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, MyRulesWeightSingleton.getRuleWeight(1));
end
```

The *Singleton* would look like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyRulesWeightSingleton {

    private static MyRulesWeightSingleton instance;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> weights;

    private MyRulesWeightSingleton() {
        this.weights = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }

    public static MyRulesWeightSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyRulesWeightSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isRuleActive(int ruleId) {
        Integer weight = weights.get(ruleId);
        return (weight != null && weight > 0);
    }

    public int getRuleWeight(int ruleId) {
        Integer weight = weights.get(ruleId);
        if (weight != null) {
            return weight;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //Allows you to put and remove weights information
    //before running planner.
    public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getWeights() {
        return this.weights;
    }
}
```

PS: Our actual problem here was a bit more complicated than this, so I simplified our approach for didatical reasons. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be the creation of

```
class Guard {
    String rulename; ... }
```

and the addition of patterns to your rule

```
rule rule_1
when
    Guard( rulename == "rule_1" )
    ...
```

Then you need to insert the Guard facts for the rules that should be blocked.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the last bit. I do know how to check for the input, and see if the rule exists, I just don't know what method I would call for the rule to be blocked and not checked any further. Currently, my program sees if the rule is on the list of execution; if it isn't, the "then" part is left empty. However that doesn't seem to be an efficient way to go about it, ideally the program wouldn't regard the rule at all, once it finds out it's not there. But I don't know what method I should call for that to happen.

Comment: You must call kieSession.insert(f) where f is a suitable Gard object.